# Is it possible to run a Flutter app on a real iPhone connected to a Windows machine in VSCode?

Tags: iphone, windows, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

If I connect a physical iPhone to my Windows computer via usb, is it possible to run a Flutter app on it in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, you need to install XCode and XCode Command Tools in order to build for iOS. For those you need to use MacOS.